# Facebook iOS SDK - openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions never timeouts

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am using the facebook SDK in my application and i am trying to simulate the case the user does not have or loose the internet connection.

So i disconnect from Internet and i call the [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:::] method.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
       ....
    } else {
       ....
    }
}];
```

Unfortunately the call is never timeout...

Does anyone know what i am missing here?

Comment: Hope you'll get a better answer but there are some workarounds to this starting a `NSTimer` when firing the request and killing it if the request is sucessfull. If timer fires you destroy the request and start again if you want.